# Space in parameters for Azure SQL Data Warehouse connection string

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc, azure-synapse

I am upgrading my JDBC connection string right now on my Azure SQL Data Warehouse to the new specifications, specifically, adding the following to it: `Application Name=MyApp`.

Here's my issue. I connect to my server using the following string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;database=mydb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

If I add the application name to my string, it will become the following:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;database=mydb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;Application Name=MyApp
```

See the space between `Application` and `Name`?

My question is - is this right? And do I need to encode that space to something like `%20`?

Nowhere in the Microsoft docs do they mention this necessity if the connection string is a URL..

EDIT 1: I found something sort of related to the JDBC connection strings, but it doesn't specify any params that may contain spaces: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-connect-overview/

EDIT 2: Found this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

> Escaping Values in the Connection URL
>   You might have to escape certain parts of the connection URL values because of the inclusion of special characters such as spaces, semicolons, and quotation marks. The JDBC driver supports escaping these characters if they are enclosed in braces. For example, {;} escapes a semicolon.
>   Escaped values can contain special characters (especially '=', ';', '[]', and space) but cannot contain braces. Values that must be escaped and contain braces should be added to a properties collection.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to add any escape characters for the Application Name property. The comments about escaping apply to the URL component of your connection string and not the whole connection string.

I believe, though, that you should be using ApplicationName as the property value anyways.

Comment: Yup you are right, at least for Azure SQL. Do you know if it's the same thing for Azure SQL DW? Also how do I check within Azure SQL DW that the app name is set correctly?